# IHS (inverse hyperbolic sine) option of mhurdle in r does not work

Tags: r, statistics, estimation

I hope this thread finds you well.

I am trying to use Box-Cox double hurdle model and Inverse Hyperbolic Sine (IHS) double hurdle model since the dependent variable of my data is non-normal. The problem I face is that I could not find some appropriate package to run the IHS model.

I tried 'mhurdle' in R and could get the result using Box-Cox. But the 'IHS' option does not work (only saying that "object 'lin' not found", even when other distribution options such as log-normal and box-cox work)

Is there any package or code to help me with this issue?